# Docker volumes newbie questions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

For a service I've defined a volume as (an extract of my yml file)

```
services:
   wordpress:
      volumes:
         - wp_data:/var/www/html
      networks:
            - wpsite
networks: 
    wpsite:
volumes:
   wp_data:
      driver: local
```

I'm aware on a Windows 10 filesystem that the WP volumes won't be readily visible to me as they'll exist within the linux VM. Alternatively I'd have to provide a path argument to be able view my WP installation e.g.

```
volumes:
   - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

But my question is what is the point of the 'driver: local' option, is this default. I've tried with & without this option and can't see the difference.

Secondly what does this do? In my yml file I've commented it out to no ill effect that I can see!?

```
networks: 
    wpsite:
```

Comment: after spinup the container you can exec container and look for dir structure, you will find the difference of use of  `driver: local`

Comment: If you remove only the `networks:` section, you should receive an error like `Service wordpress uses an undefined network`. If you remove the `networks:` section as well as the network from the service, then the service will use the `default` network which basically leads you to the same result as using a dummy `wpsite` network that has nothing configured, only with a different name(wpsite instead of default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First question:**
The `--driver` or `-d` option defaults to local. `driver: local` is redundant. On Windows, the local driver does not support any options. If you were running docker on a Linux machine, you would've had some options: Official documentation here - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

**Second question:**
In each section `networks:`/`volumes:`/`services:` you basically declare the resources you need for your deployment.
In other words, creating an analogy with a virtual machine, you can think about it like this: you need to create a virtual disk named `wp_data` and a virtual network named `wpsite`.
Then, you want your `wordpress` service, to mount the the `wp_data` disk under `/var/www/html` and to connect to the `wpsite` subnet.

You can use the following docker commands to display the resources that are created behind the scenes by your compose file:
`docker ps` - show containers
`docker volume ls` - show docker volumes
`docker network ls` - show docker networks

Hint: once you created a network or a volume, unless you manually delete it, it will not be destroyed automatically. You can clean-up manually the resources and experiment yourself by removing/adding more resources from your compose file.

---

**Updated to answer question in comment:**
If you run your docker on a Windows host, you probably enabled hyper-v. This allowed Windows to create a Linux VM, on top of which your docker engine is running.
With the docker engine installed, docker can then create "virtual resources" such as virtual networks, virtual disks(volumes), containers(people often compare containers to VMs), services, containers etc.

Let's look at the following section from your compose file:

```
volumes:
   wp_data:
      driver: local
```

This will create a virtual disk managed by docker, named `wp_data`. The volume is not created directly on your Windows host file system, but instead it is being created inside the Linux VM that is running on top of the HyperV that is running on your Windows host. If you want to know precisely where, you can either execute `docker inspect <containerID>` and look for the mounts that you have on that container, or `docker volume ls` then `docker volume inspect <volumeID>` and look for the key "Mountpoint" to get the actual location.

Comment: Not sure I follow, let me see. So the WP service will mount the volume _wp_data_ in the linux VM in Win10. Using the named network _wpsite_, _wp_data_ will link up with `/var/www/html`. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope this answers your question on how volumes are created on Docker running on Windows

Comment: Yes thank you that clarifies it to a point where I feel like I'm more engaged with whats going what each line is doing. I'm invested a lot of time in learning docker i.e. watching YT videos and I found you've got to do this to pick up increments in knowledge as no one source explains it all. So thanks for helping me on my Docker journey :)